# How to annotate a Number parameter in SpringFox?

Tags: swagger, springfox

I am using Swagger configuration for REST API with Java and SpringFox. I have an API method parameter of type `Number`, which is not being displayed in Swagger UI.

My method parameter and Swagger documentation is like this -

```
@ApiParam(value = "Unique, system generated identifier of student.", required = true) @RequestParam("serialNo") Number serialNo
```

I have also tried using `type = "number", format = "float"` in Swagger documentation but no success!

Does Swagger only support primitive data types? 
What I need to do for `Number` type fields?

Comment: Which framework are you using - Springfox/etc.? Can you post the generated Swagger JSON/YAML spec and a screenshot of Swagger UI?

Comment: I am using springfox framework.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/ would suggest that you could use `integer` with `format` `int32` or `int64`